# How to pass arbitrary lambdas as params to function (to get naming hierarchy)?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have some (what I think are...) `MemberExpression`'s wrapped in lambas.

```
void Main()
{
    Foo<Person>(x => x.Name, x => x.Id, x => x.Address);
}

void Foo<TSource>(params Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>>[] lambdas)
{
    foreach (var lambda in lambdas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetHierarchicalName(lambda));
    }
}

string GetHierarchicalName<TSource, TValue>(Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> lambda)
{
    var member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    var hierarchy = new Stack<string>();

    if (member == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("You need to pass a lambda which references a member, silly!");
    }

    do
    {
        hierarchy.Push(member.Member.Name);
    } while (member.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess && (member = member.Expression as MemberExpression) != null);

    return String.Join("", hierarchy.ToArray());
}
```

My end goal is that `Foo` will output "Name", "Id" and "Address" (additionally, when passing a lambda such as `x => x.Foo.Bar.Baz`, "FooBarBaz" will be output).

However, at the moment I'm not specifying `TValue` for `Foo`; I can't, since each of the lambda's could return a different value... *but* I don't care, since all I need is the property path they're referencing.

I tried using `object` in place of `TValue`, but when a lambda returns an `int`, the lambda passed to `GetHierarchicalName` ends up being a `Convert`, rather than a `MemberExpression`.

How can I get around not specifying `TValue`, such that I can pass arbitrary lambdas to `Foo()`, and have it output the path to the member each lambda is referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to declare a bunch of overloads of the form `Foo<TSource, T1, ..., TN>`, similar to how `Action` and `Func` themselves have overloads for up to 16 arguments. For example:

```
void Foo<TSource, T1, T2, T3>(Expression<Func<TSource, T1>> m1, Expression<Func<TSource, T2>> m2, Expression<Func<TSource, T3>> m3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetHierarchicalName(m1));
    Console.WriteLine(GetHierarchicalName(m2));
    Console.WriteLine(GetHierarchicalName(m3));
}
```

This can then be called as:

```
Foo<string, int, string>(x => x.Name, x => x.Id, x => x.Address);
```

To get the compiler to infer types, Foo has to accept an extra argument of type `TSource`:

```
Foo<TSource, T1, T2, T3>(TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, T1>> m1, ...) { ... }
```

so it can be called as:

```
Foo(person, x => x.Name, x => x.Id, x => x.Address);
```

But all of that is a lot of work for little gain.

A conversion is represented by a `UnaryExpression` with NodeType `ExpressionType.Convert`. In this case, its `Operand` property contains the `MemberExpression` you're looking for.

Comment: Your first suggestion is untenable because of all the variations I would have to create; `<string, int>`, `<int, string>`, `<int, boolean>`... the list would go on forever! Your second suggestion may well be the way to go though.

Comment: They're generic parameters, so you don't need to create those variations, just overloads for the number of parameters you want to accept. You may have to perform some trickery to get the compiler to infer their types however, such as passing an extra argument of type `TSource`, otherwise you'll have to specify the types in each call to `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks; I ended up taking this approach. Ended up having to declare  11 different overloads of varying parameter lengths, but it works! Now  I understand the solution, it doesn't even seem that much of a messy solution :).

Answer (score 2):

`int` values need to be boxed to be represented as objects, that's why you're getting a `Convert` expression. You have to get the `Convert` expression's `Operand` instead of `Body`:

```
    var member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member == null && lambda.Body is UnaryExpression && lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
    {
       member = (lambda.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some code that can code with any expression, you don't need to specify it is a typed expression so you can just use the base Expression class.

Here is some code from the utilities class I use, it has some code to handle the Converts and strip them out. Note I wrote this in LinqPad, so you may need to replace Dump() with something like Console.WriteLine if you want to run it elsewhere.

```
    void Main()
    {               
        Foo(x => x.Name, x => x.Id, x => x.Address);
    }

    void Foo(params Expression<Func<Bar, object>>[] lambdas)
    {
        foreach (var lambda in lambdas)
        {
            ExpressionToString(lambda).Dump();
        }
    }

    public static string ExpressionToString(Expression selector)
    {
        string left, right, result;
        switch (selector.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                var memberExpression = selector as MemberExpression;
                right = (memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo).Name;
                if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                {
                    left = ExpressionToString(memberExpression.Expression);
                    result = left + right;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = right;
                }

                break;
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                var method = selector as MethodCallExpression;
                left = ExpressionToString(method.Arguments[0]);
                right = ExpressionToString(method.Arguments[1]);
                result = left + right;
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Lambda:
                var lambda = selector as LambdaExpression;
                result = ExpressionToString(lambda.Body);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Quote:
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                var unary = selector as UnaryExpression;
                result = ExpressionToString(unary.Operand);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be MemberAccess, Call, Quote, Convert or Lambda");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }

        public String Id { get; set; }

        public String Address { get; set; }
    }
```

This will produce:

```
Name    
Id    
Address
```

Comment: Humm... thanks for your answer. When I swap out all the `Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>>`'s for just `Expression`', then I then get a compile time error over the lambda's, saying that "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' because it is not a delegate type". Here's the code I'm using; http://pastebin.com/YcezC4JH (it's the method signatures of your code I'm checking here; I haven't implemented your function body yet).

Comment: You still need to tell .net somewhere what your lambda type is, I've updated the code with a complete working example